# What is ai.js files in new Empty Web Project VS2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

It's just an curious question. Whenever I create new "Empty” WebApplication project without any core dependencies In VS2015, I get 2 `.js` files under script folder.

Here is screenshot.

[image]

My questions is:

> 1.For what purpose these `.js` files are included?
>
> 2.What they do?
>
> 3.Are they safe to remove?

I searched over Google and found they are **Application Insights API** but did't get what they actually do?

Comment: You probably checked "Add Application Insights to project" when created the project. Uninstall the relevant NuGet packages and delete the scripts if you don't want it.

Comment: @haim770 yes, the "Add Application Insights to project" was already checked,your comment answers 3rd ans, do you know what is purpose of Application Insights?

Comment: Diagnostics, monitoring, analyzing, logging etc. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/